# Clicker App: Saves Clicks not Correctly

Tags: android

I made a Clicker App (like cookie clicker). But when i Restart the App, the app saves the clicks, but only visible, so i mean when i click on the button, the clicks will be set to 0 again. So my question: Is my SharedPreference correct, or did i have done an mistake?
My complete MainActivity.java:

```
package com.rage.clicker;

import android.content.Context; 
import android.content.SharedPreferences; 
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.SoundPool; 
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; 
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View; import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils; 
import android.widget.Button; 
import android.widget.EditText; 
import android.widget.ImageView; 
import android.widget.TextView; 
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import static com.rage.clicker.R.id.highscore_text; 
import static com.rage.clicker.R.id.textView88;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    SoundPool mySound;
    int playClick;
    private final String TAG = this.getClass().getName();
    ImageView hi;
    TextView tv_clicks;
    TextView ht;
    ImageView b_click;
    Button save;
    int clicks;
    SharedPreferences sf;
    public static final String preference = "pref";
    public static final String saveIt = "saveKey";
    private TextView highScoreView;
    private TextView currentScoreView;
    private int currentScore;
    private int highScore;
    private String highScoreString;
    private String currentScoreString;
    private SharedPreferences msharedPreferences;

    private static final String FILENAME = "PreferencesFilename";
    private static final String VAL_KEY = "ValueKey";
    private EditText editText;
    private TextView TEV; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Speichern laden
        TEV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView88);
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences(FILENAME, 0);
        TEV.setText(sharedPrefs.getString(VAL_KEY, ""));
        //Speichern laden
        msharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        mySound = new SoundPool(100, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        playClick = mySound.load(this, R.raw.click, 1);
        tv_clicks = (TextView) findViewById(textView88);
        b_click = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        hi = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        b_click = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        ht = (TextView) findViewById(highscore_text);
        final TextView TV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.highscore_text);
        currentScoreString = getString(R.string.current_score);
        highScoreString = getString(R.string.high_score);
        currentScore = clicks;
        highScore = msharedPreferences.getInt(highScoreString, 0);

        save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        save.setOnClickListener( 
            new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast dumplings= Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Adolf4", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                dumplings.show();
            }
        });

        b_click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final ImageView zoom = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                final Animation zoomAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.size);
                zoom.startAnimation(zoomAnimation);
                mySound.play(playClick, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
                clicks++;

                tv_clicks.setText("Klicks: " + clicks);
                ht.setText(currentScoreString + ": Test" + currentScore); 
            }
        });
    }

    protected void init() {
        currentScoreView.setText(currentScoreString + ": asd" + currentScore);
        highScoreView.setText(highScoreString + ":34 " + highScore);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop(); 
        //Speichern
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences(FILENAME, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
        editor.putString(VAL_KEY, TEV.getText().toString());
        editor.commit();
        //Speichern
    } 
}
```

Comment: You never restore value of `clicks` so of course it's zero

Comment: @Sami Kuhmonen oh, and can you give me maybe an code for that?

Comment: @NoNameCoding It's the same as you already do for the high score.

Comment: Man, sorry but i dont understand what you mean ._.

Comment: You need to store the `clicks` in `SharedPreferences` and then restore it. You already do this for `highScore`. So do the same thing for `clicks`.

Comment: I cant find where i restored it for Highscore? I dont saved it for Highscore only for the Current score

Answer (score 1):

When you save data, you take click's count value from `TEV` `TextView`, but inside `onClick` event you update `tv_clicks` and `TEV` always remains zero by default. You should save clicks value like this

```
editor.putInt(VAL_KEY, clicks);
```

Then you should load clicks value and set it in the `TextView`:

```
clicks = sharedPrefs.getInt(VAL_KEY, 0)
TEV.setText(String.valueOf(clicks));
```

Comment: I don't think this is the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure. But this answer won't fix anything that has to do with stopping the app then restarting it.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, but you adviced same thing in comments to the subject, we need to store clicks in SharedPreferences, ok, and we need show current clicks in TextView, I would be thankful if you would explain me my mistake.

Comment: I saw the older version that only mentioned `setText()` and didn't say anything about the `SharedPreferences`. It looks like you were editing just about the same time I posted my comment.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, thanks, I will not hurry with the answer next time.

Comment: Guys, sorry but can you please give me a code for that? I try it the whole time but i dont get it.

Comment: Oh, i tried yours @Code-Apprentice, but when i start the app it crashes :/java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rage.clicker/com.rage.clicker.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Comment: @NoNameCoding, I think you try load `clicks` through `getString()` method or old string value load with `VAL_KEY`, try to use another value for this.